# Internal test download not being proposed by the Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-internal-testing

I have recently deployed an `internal test` version of a Google Play application, that I created on the Google Play Console. This application targets Android version 5.0 or later.

I registered the Google email account of a device I would like to test the application on.
This device is a Samsung G800F and has Android `6.0.1` installed.

Does that device (or Play Store application version) support internal testing? I can't see anything about internal testing, even when explictly clicking a PlayConsole-generated link, sent over by email, for that test version.

What is the minimum Android (or Play Store application?) version required for internal testing?

If the device indeed has no support for internal testing, I can indeed purchase another device for testing, but I would like to be sure I am not doing anything wrong first.

Comment: Did you accept internal test invitation on desktop ?

Comment: I did, but it works now: I had to leave the program, accept the invite again and this time I was proposed to download a beta version in the Play Store.